# Which attribute to use as the PK?

Tags: database, primary-key, normalization, entity-relationship, erd

I have a table called Vehicles.
And this table has 8 attributes:

- Vehicle ID
- Registration No
- Make (Honda, Ford, etc..)
- Model
- Colour
- number of passengers
- odometer's current reading
- features

Should I use the Vehicle ID as the PK or the reg_no as the PK?

Comment: Are you able to get the VIN for each vehicle?  It would accurately represent the uniqueness of the object regardless of sale, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since the table is called vehicles, I would say the Vehicle ID. But this also depends on the fact if a vehicle is entered in the database multiple times, as in, multiple owners.

Comment: oh it's actually a transport service provider. however, each of these vehicles will need regular maintenance, and another table called maintenance is created. for this maintenance table, it has odometer's current reading, maintenance startdate, final cost, and description. Which attribute shall be the PK for this table then?

Comment: Maintenance ID, with a FK to Vehicle ID

Comment: to transport staffs of a particular company to specific places. vehicles is just one of the many entities.

Comment: is it possible to use the vehicle ID for the maintenance table as the PFK?

Comment: No, since a car could have multiple maintenances.

I would advice you to have a look at some normalization courses, since this is the basic of normalization.